# Deploying node in maas error

Tags: partitioning, juju, maas

I deploy the node after they are commissioned, it is failed. The screen prints out a lot of messages, repeatedly says

```
cannot create symlink to/usr/share/ca-certifcates/mozilla/verisign_Class_1_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-G3.crt
```

and

```
No space left on device\ntar: ./etc/ssl/certs/Actalis_Authentication_Root_CA.pem
```

I do not know the meaning of these two messages, but they are printed out the entire screen and the deploy is failed. Thanks for any ideas and suggestions.